# Reporting a spam

Tags: spam-prevention

I believe I was hacked last night. The worst thing is whoever did this has now changed my password and I can no longer access my main email account since this morning. I am petrified to know someone has now got my personal details!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Yes your details are out there...

Answer (score 3):

Change **all** of your passwords **immediately** preferably from another computer. If you use online banking **call your bank**!

Read the following links:

[7 Tips for When Your Email Account Is Hacked](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/7-tips-email-account-hacked,news-17623.html):

> Here are seven steps to keep you and your email contacts safe after your email account has been hijacked or otherwise compromised.

[What To Do When Your Email Gets Hacked](http://www.techlicious.com/tip/what-to-do-when-your-email-gets-hacked/):

Lists steps to take to get everything back in order.